# Alternative to arange with numpy arrays as boundaries

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two numpy arrays acting as lower and upper boundaries of a range of vectors that I want to generate.

In the a similar way that arange() works, I would like to generate the intermediate members as in the example:

```
lower_boundary = np.array([1,1])
upper_boundary = np.array([3,3])

expected_result = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]]
```

The result can be a list or another numpy array. So far I have managed to workaround this scenario with nested loops, but the dimensions of 'lower_boundary' and 'upper_boundary' may vary, and my approach is not applicable.

In a typical scenario, both boundaries have *at least* 4 dimensions.

Comment: What's the expected output if `upper_boundary = np.array([4,3])`?

Comment: For that case:

    expected_result = [[1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [4,3]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [np.indicies](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to get a range of index values of your desired range (`upper_boundary - lower boundary + 1`), reshape it to your needs (`reshape(len(upper_boundary),-1)`) and add your `lower_boundry` to values resulting in;

```
>>> np.indices(upper_boundary - lower_boundary + 1).reshape(len(upper_boundary),-1).T + lower_boundary
array([[1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Edit: I forgot to correct the code before posting, it should be like this.
Thanks @Divakar for the fix.

Comment: Think the correct/generic version would be something like : `np.indices(upper_boundary - lower_boundary + 1).reshape(len(upper_boundary),-1).T + lower_boundary`.

Comment: @Divakar Good catch, I was using 3,3 instead of said variables, forgot to correct it. Will fix it now, thanks.

Comment: Yup, the pitfalls of OP listing simplistic samples :)

Comment: Great answer, I was not aware of np.indicies in this particular instance.